# annotate: whether a given value exists in m2m field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, drf-queryset

I have a query that retrieve an object like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I want to check whether a given tag (say, 1) exists in the `tags` field of the object, and `annotate` the result of the check as a field of the object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tagged": true
}
```

This is what I came up with

```
annotate(
    tagged=Exists(
        Articles.tag_set.through.objects.filter(
            article_id=OuterRef("pk"), tag_id=tag.id
        )
    )
)
```

Since the relation `tags` is already loaded by the primary query, having a secondary query seems redundant to me.

Is there an easier way to structure this query? Something close to the filter `in` lookup syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming tags is an ArrayField

```
    q = Article.objects.annotate(
        tagged=Exists(
            Article.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('id'), tags__contains=[1])
        )
    )
```